# Can I send a multipart email with Jade SmtpConnection

Tags: jade-platform

I'm trying to send a multipart email using SmtpConnection. This is what I have:

```
vars
    smtp: SmtpConnection;
    cnatt: CnAttachment;
    fileName: String;
    file: File;
begin
    create smtp transient;
    //set up smtpconnection ...
    smtp.message = 'Text content';

    create cnatt transient;
    cnatt.setContentType("text/html");
    cnatt.encodingType := "Base64";
    fileName := app.mUserTempDirectory & 'content.html';
    create file transient;
    file.openOutput(fileName);
    file.writeString('<html><body><b>HTML content</b></body></html>');
    file.close();
    cnatt.fileName := fileName;
    cnatt.mySmtpConnection := smtp;

    // send and clean up...
```

The HTML content comes through as an attachment.
I think what I need is to set the content disposition of the attachment to inline, but there does not seem to be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CardSchema provides a CnSmtpInline class, which is similar to an attachment (both inherit from CnMIME).

Class text indicates it's intended for embedding content in multipart SMTP message, so I'm assuming this'll provide the functionality you're after (not something I've had to do myself).